# $http.post request can't find method in controller

Tags: angularjs, http-post, http-status-code-404, asp.net-web-api2

I have a *AddCategory()* method in my *Controller*:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
    public class CategoryController : ApiController
    {
            ....
      [Route("addCategory")]
      [HttpPost]
      public void AddCategory(string category)
      {
        var getCat = category;
      }
```

At the my *Home.html* i have button *Save New Category* i wrote the $http.post method for it:

```
 var testString = "TEST String";
            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/addCategory',
                data: testString,

            };
            $http(req).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log("Success");
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log("Eror");
                });
```

But i have the next error:

> angular.js:11442 POST http://localhost:6059/api/addCategory 404 (Not
>   Found)

At the *Network* bookmark in *Development console* i finded the error: 
[image]

may be it's important but i disabled *XML* in *WebApiConfig.cs*:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
        json.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
        json.Remove(json.XmlFormatter);
```

May be somebody knows how i can change it  ? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Can you use postman and send a request at /api/addCategory?

Comment: yes, i done it: error: *No action was found on the controller 'Category' that matches the request*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You method Post need to return IHttpActionResult. or your request http always returns code 404.

Try this :

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
    public class CategoryController : ApiController
    {
            ....
      [Route("addCategory")]
      [HttpPost]
      public IHttpActionResult AddCategory(string category)
      {
        var getCat = category;
        if(getCat != null)
          return Ok();

        return NotFound();
      }
```

I advice you to use Api Rest in C# with $resource angular. In my mind, it's the best pattern.

Comment: i have troubles with serialization and problems with sending object to my controller, it's my first http.post request.  Thanks for your unswer!

Comment: U can use [FromUri] or [FromBody] in parameters of AddCategory

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the service you are calling, 404 means not found:

[404 http error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

therefore something in the service URL or in your local server is not working.